Positive semi-definitiveness condition for multidimensional minimization case

We study the nonlinear problem
\begin{equation} \underset{\mathbb{R}^2}{\text{min}}f(x)
 \end{equation}


where $f(x)=x_1^2+x_2e^{x_1}-x_1x_2+x_2^2$
Evaluate whether the problem is convex.

For a problem to be convex we need consider the multidimensional case the Hessian matrix of second derivatives which must be positive
semi-definite; that is, at every point $x \in S$
$$y^T\nabla^2 f (x)y \ge 0 \ \ \forall y$$
So we have the gradient:
\begin{equation}
    \nabla f(x_1,x_2)=\begin{pmatrix}
        2x_1+x_2e^{x_1}-x_2 \\
        e^{x_1}-x_1+2x_2\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
and the Hessian:
\begin{equation}
    \nabla f^2(x_1,x_2)=\begin{pmatrix}
        2 +x_2e^{x_1}  & x_2-1\\
        e^{x_1}-1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
However, the Hessian is not composed of scalars, but of functions, so I cannot calculate whether it satisfies
$x \in S$
$$y^T\nabla^2 f (x)y \ge 0 \ \ \forall y.$$ So my question is, is it sufficient to calculate the  determinant, which is $$ x_2  + e^{x_1} (x_2 + 1) + 3,$$ and consider when it is positive - as a sufficient condition for convexity of the multidimensional case?
Thanks

There seems to be some information missing. What is $S$?

S would be defined if it was a constrained problem, but since it is unconstrained, then S is the real plane.

Your Hessian matrix is not properly calculated. Keep in mind that, for regular functions, the Hessian matrix will always be symmetric. So, the Hessian is actually
$$
\nabla^2 f(x)= \begin{pmatrix} 2 + x_2 e^{x_1} & e^{x_1}-1\\e^{x_1}-1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
$$
This is not a convex problem in $\mathbb{R}^2$ because, depending on the values of $(x_1,x_2)$, the Hessian is not necessarily positive semi-definite. For example, for $x_1=x_2=1$, the Hessian is positive-definite, while for $x_1=1, x_2 = -1$ it is indefinite.
Regarding your question about the sign of the determinant, the answers is no. You need to analyse the sign of the principal minors (one of them is the determinant, the other is the $(1,1)$ entry of the hessian) or, if needed, the sign of the eigenvalues.

Maybe I see something that doesn't exists, but aren't your Hessian and mine exactly the same?

@Superunknown your Hessian has $x_2-1$ as the $(1,2)$ entry.

You're right....I am lost in the clouds... Thanks!....
